ngClass doesn't work even with static classes
I am working on a library with Angular incorporating StoryBook, I tried to add a class associated with the story "Primary" but it didn't work, so I tried to add it statically and it doesn't work either.
This is my code html:
<button [ngClass]="'Primary'">{{label}}</button>

This is my code css:
.Primary{
    background-color: aqua;
}`


This is my component button:

`@Component({
  selector: 'lib-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css'
})
export class ButtonComponent {
@Input() primary: boolean = false;
@Input() label: string = 'Click';
}

This is my storie
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular/';

import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

const meta: Meta<ButtonComponent> = {
    title: 'Components/Button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<ButtonComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    primary: true,
    label: 'Button',
     
  },
};

I appreciate the help in advance

You are missing the import for using [ngClass] you can either use the import NgClass or CommonModule which contain all the common directives (e.g. *ngFor, *ngIf, ngStyle, etc)
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
...

...
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgClass], // or CommonModule from same import location!
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css'
})
export class ButtonComponent {
    @Input() primary: boolean = false;
    @Input() label: string = 'Click';
}

